# easiest way to get list of USA states

Tags: java, jsp

What would be the easiest way to get list of US states?

I need to use these in the JSP form, currently I have enum that works just fine. However I am wondering how this could be improved...

```
public enum State {
    AL("Alabama"),
    MT("Montana"),
    AK("Alaska"),
    NE("Nebraska"),
    AZ("Arizona"),
    NV("Nevada"),
    AR("Arkansas"),
    NH("NewHampshire"),
    CA("California"),
    NJ("NewJersey"),
    CO("Colorado"),
    NM("NewMexico"),
    CT("Connecticut"),
    NY("NewYork"),
    DE("Delaware"),
    NC("NorthCarolina"),
    FL("Florida"),
    ND("NorthDakota"),
    GA("Georgia"),
    OH("Ohio"),
    HI("Hawaii"),
    OK("Oklahoma"),
    ID("Idaho"),
    OR("Oregon"),
    IL("Illinois"),
    PA("Pennsylvania"),
    IN("Indiana"),
    RI("RhodeIsland"),
    IA("Iowa"),
    SC("SouthCarolina"),
    KS("Kansas"),
    SD("SouthDakota"),
    KY("Kentucky"),
    TN("Tennessee"),
    LA("Louisiana"),
    TX("Texas"),
    ME("Maine"),
    UT("Utah"),
    MD("Maryland"),
    VT("Vermont"),
    MA("Massachusetts"),
    VA("Virginia"),
    MI("Michigan"),
    WA("Washington"),
    MN("Minnesota"),
    WV("WestVirginia"),
    MS("Mississippi"),
    WI("Wisconsin"),
    MO("Missouri"),
    WY("Wyoming");
private String state;
private State(String state) {
            this.state = state;
}
public String getStatusCode() {
            return this.state;
}
}
```

I then pass it to the model and in JSP (Spring form) call these like:

```
<form:form>
...
    <form:select path="state" id="state">
        <form:options items="${usaStates}"  />
    </form:select>
    <form:errors path="state" cssClass="error"/>

...
</form:form>
```

Comment: Enums are a pretty good way to go. Downside: In case the number of US states ever changes ([which might happen](http://www.puertoricoreport.com/pierluisi-introduces-historic-legislation/)) though, you need to touch your the code. On a side note, don't call the enum ``State``, which is highly ambiguous. You might even externalize it into a config file.

Comment: thanks for spotting that @devnull

Answer (score 2):

For ultimate flexibility you could stick the states in a database table (if you have a database available to you; I assume you do since its a web application). You could then even stick the values in a cache such as EhCache.

Answer (score 1):

Really, what you have works fine overall, but if you are looking for another way to do it then
I would suggest using a `HashMap`.

It tends to be more clean and you keep them all in one group, all assigned with a `key` (Abbreviation of State) and its `Value` (Full name of state). Then, you can loop through the HashMap and gather the values. I'm not the best with `JSP`, but I know that you can use a `HashMap` with it! Best of luck